# tensorflow core dumped after check failed

Tags: tensorflow

#### System information

- **I leveraged keras using TensorFlow backend to train a batch of 300*300*3 rgb image.
- **Linux CentOS 7**:
- **TensorFlow installed from binary**:
- **TensorFlow version 1.4/1.5**:
- **Python version 3.6**:

#### Describe the problem

I used the following code to build CNN model

```python
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, (5, 5), activation='relu', input_shape=(3, height, width), data_format='channels_first'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=36, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

batch_steps = get_training_data_batch()
model.fit_generator(training_data_generator(), steps_per_epoch=batch_steps, epochs=15, verbose=2)
model.summary()

x_test, y_test = get_testing_data()
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("score:", score[1])

batch_size = 2000
def training_data_generator():
    for benchmark_num in training_benchmark_num_list:
        x_data, y_data = get_feature_data(benchmark_num)
        samples_totals = x_data.shape[0]
        print("samples totals:", samples_totals)
        batch = samples_totals / batch_size + 1
        for x in range(0, int(batch), 1):
            x_sub_data = x_data[x*batch_size:(x+1)*batch_size]
            y_sub_data = y_data[x*batch_size:(x+1)*batch_size]

            x_train = x_sub_data.reshape(x_sub_data.shape[0], 3, height, width)
            x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
            x_train /= 255
            y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_sub_data, 2)
            yield (x_train, y_train)
```

Program shows the error before code dumped:

> F tensorflow/core/kernels/maxpooling_op.cc:177] 
>       Check failed: input_backprop_index >= in_start && input_backprop_index < in_end Invalid input backprop index: -1491167680, 2803712000, 2806515712

I traced tensorflow source code, it should be check operation. And backprop index can't be negative. I don't know tensorflow well, why can appear such problem? I think this error is root cause of code dumped. Could you help me solve this problem?